# Location of core code for database connection and get_header

Tags: php, mysql, headers, core

I understand WP well enough to create a custom theme at a basic level, but have no experience with the core code. I've also just finished a book on basic php and mysql coding.

I'd like to look 'under the hood' of WP to try and put those together. Can someone tell me:

- Where to find the files that code for the WP-Mysql connection? (as in, `mysqli_connect` ...)
- Where to find the files that code for the `get_header()` function? (which I assume will have something like `include(header.php)` )

Thanks!

Comment: Just drop the whole `wordpress` folder in your favorite code editor and do a global search. And follow @Patj suggestions bellow.

Comment: [How do you code for WordPress?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/31967/12615)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the usual caveat -- *Don't modify core code*. (Certainly not on a production site.)

If you read the documentation on the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/), you'll notice that most if not all of the pages in, say, the [Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) have a section called **Source File**.  Clicking the link located there will take you to the file in [trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/) where the particular function lives.

For instance, the Codex page for [`the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) points you to [`wp-includes/post-template.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post-template.php#L0).

Your specific questions:

- The [`$wpdb()` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Source_File) is in `wp-includes/wp-db.php`.
- [`get_header()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header#Source_File) is in `wp-includes/general-template.php`.

Sometimes, though, you'll have to hunt all over the WordPress codebase to follow the track of *how does this work?*  You'll find that functions call other functions, which call other functions, which apply filters, and so forth.  There's a lot of digging, sometimes, to understand how something in WordPress actually works.  Do it.  It's worth it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this extremely helpful and informative response! Just what I was hoping for; I'll start diggin'. . . 

Is there, in your knowledge, any generalized tutorial of how to begin leaning wp core? It would be very useful for me to have some structure to my learning around this.

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.

Comment: Silly question probably, but maybe I'm lucky. `get_header()` is still located in the same place, so your answer is still correct. But if I would add the function `get_nav()` in the same way as that `get_header()` and `get_footer()` are written, create such a nav file in the correct folder, and call the function on the pages, do you think that would suffice for it to work? Quite often I need to have the `nav` outside of the `header` in the source code.